# How do I enable intellisense for Expression Blend 4 trial version?

Tags: intellisense, expression-blend

I have expression blend trial version `4.0.30816.0` and there is no intellisense for the code behind or the xaml, how do I enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Ctrl + Space`. Sorry can't get any more detailed with this answer ;-)